# java wait() statement after catch clause

Tags: java

When I run the program it does not display "HIIII."
I am a novice (sort of) so please dont "hate".
Is my wait() statement wrong? Or what am I doing wrong?
Is it the ArrayIndexOutOfBounds catch clause? Please help!

`[edit]` oh so is it the main method?? that it doesnt do anything?
`[edit]` i know the wait and notify is wrong... please don't mention it.

```
//this is the whole class
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class none {

static boolean game;
final static boolean on = true;
final static boolean off = false;
static boolean cheatMode;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    game = on;
    boolean tru = true;
    try{
        if(tru = Boolean.parseBoolean(args[0])){
            cheatMode = on;
            System.out.println("Cheats are on.");
        }
        }
        catch(java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Ignore this error, it's from not running it on the command prompt.");
        }
}



public class console extends Thread{
    public void run(){
        try{
        wait();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"HIIII");
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("The console glitched...");
        }
//hiiii
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"HIIII");
        }
    public class mainThingy extends Thread{
        public void run() {
        if(game = on)
        notify();
    }
}
    }
}
```

Comment: *"plz dont hate"*  Please spell all the letters of words like 'please'.  It helps the reader and that in turn helps them to like the writer.  +1 for posting a short code.

Comment: where are you using `console` and `MainThnigy`? When you call `wait` in `console`, which statement are you using the wake-up that waiting thread?

Comment: You `main` method doesn't do anything.  It checks the arguments, but then exists.

Comment: im trying to make the threads do it because i can't make the main method notify()... anyone know a better way to make threads wait..? where i can actually use the main method...?

Comment: I am not finding any code which is invoking the Threads `console` and `MainThingy`. Just by defining, how will they run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd advise against the standard wait()-notify() structures. There are way better methods for this: the Java concurrency package.

- [Tutorial for Java Concurrency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/)
- [API JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html)
- [JCIP, or Java Concurrency In Practice (Peierls, Bloch, Bowbeer, Holmes, Lea)](http://www.javaconcurrencyinpractice.com/)

And as you seem to be in your first steps in learning Java, I'd suggest another two books:

- [Effective Java (Bloch)](http://books.google.co.uk/books/about/Effective_Java.html?id=ZZOiqZQIbRMC&redir_esc=y)
- [Java puzzlers (Bloch, Gafter)](http://www.javapuzzlers.com/)

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be couple of issues

```
1) if(tru = Boolean.parseBoolean(args[0])){
```

Above statement is assignemt and not comparison. Use == operator.

2) Wait and notify should always be called from inside Synchronized blocks. Your code doesn't seem to be doing that.

Comment: okay... do you know a good place to learn about wait notify etc? (sorry) thanks.

Comment: +1 for pointing out the == vs = error - though in exactly this case, the behaviour is the same. But it would be a nasty, puzzling error to debug, if the value of tru would have been used later in the code :)

Comment: @Minecrafterguy64 http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/thread-signaling.html This page shud be an excellent read.

Answer (score 0):

`>java none true` will print only `Cheats are on`. But your question is about printing `Hiii`. Isn't it ? You have got that in `JOptionPane` dialog inside the `console` class. Without initializing it how can you expect your program to print `Hiii`?. Also why have you written two public classes in one file ? When you are calling `wait` and  `nottify` methods, you are also missing the `synchronized` statement. So when you start your threads `console` and `mainThingy` those will throw `IllegalMonitorStateException` anyways. So actually what are you trying to do ?

Comment: im trying to get the `mainThingy` method to  notify the `console` method but im confused with wait() and notify()... doesn't the mainThingy start console? If not sorry... but i have no idea.

Answer (score 0):

1. You `main` method doesn't actually start anything
2. `wait` and `notify` must be `synchronized` on the same monitor/lock
3. Your two threads are not sharing the same monitor/lock
4. `if (game = on)` in `mainThingy` is an assignment, not a check, it should be `if (game == on)`

**UPDATE with Example**

```
public class TestThread {

    static boolean game;
    final static boolean on = true;
    final static boolean off = false;
    static boolean cheatMode;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        game = on;
        boolean tru = true;
        try {
            if (args.length > 0) {
                if (tru = Boolean.parseBoolean(args[0])) {
                    cheatMode = on;
                    System.out.println("Cheats are on.");
                }
            }
        } catch (java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Ignore this error, it's from not running it on the command prompt.");
        }

        Console con = new Console();
        con.start();

        // Give time for the console thread to get started
        do {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(TestThread.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        } while (!con.isAlive());

        System.out.println("Start main...");
        Console.MainThingy main = new Console.MainThingy();
        main.start();

    }

    public static class Console extends Thread {

        // A shared lock that our two threads can communicate on...
        public static final Object WAIT_LOCK = new Object();

        public void run() {
            try {
                System.out.println("Waiting...");
                // Must "own" the monitor before we can call wait
                synchronized (WAIT_LOCK) {
                    WAIT_LOCK.wait();
                }
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "HIIII");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("The console glitched...");
            }
        }

        public static class MainThingy extends Thread {

            public void run() {
                if (game == on) {
                    // Must "own" the monitor before we can call notify
                    synchronized (WAIT_LOCK) {
                        System.out.println("Notify...");
                        WAIT_LOCK.notify();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Java Concurrency is fun, but it will bite you if you're not careful with it and treat it nicely.

Take a read through [Currency in Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/)